# Rolling and rerolling dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I roll $10$ initial dice.
Whenever I roll a $6$, I roll $5$ more dice.

What's the expected number of dice I'm going to throw?

I was thinking about it when trying to create a die system, but I can't solve the problem.

Comment: This can be modeled as a [branching process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process).

Comment: I read that and really seems it could be modeled as such, but I can't see how to finally get the Expected number. Could you offer a bit more guidance?

Comment: If you roll two sixes do you roll five more dice or ten more?

Comment: For each six rolled, you roll 5 more dices. So if you roll two 6's, you'll roll 10 more dices.

Comment: you expect to throw 1.6 6's, resulting in throwing $5*10/6=8.333^.$ new throws of which you expect 8.333/6 new sixes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for every six you roll you roll five more dice, then you can compute the expected number for rolling one dice $E_1$ as follows: there is a $\frac 56$ chance that the first throw is the last, and a $\frac 16$ chance that you will be rolling five dice next time. Let $E_n$ be the expected number of dice you roll if you start by rolling $n$, then you have $$E_1=1+\frac 16E_5$$

Now you could equally do this by rolling the first of the five extra dice until you finish that trial, and then the second etc - the result of rolling the first is independent of the result of rolling the second. This is just a way of saying $E_5=5E_1$ so that $$E_1=1+\frac 56E_1$$And that is easy to solve. Then you need to find $E_{10}$.

Comment: I see. So in the end I'd have that $E_{10}={10 \over 1-5p}$, where $p= {1 \over 6}$. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be modeled as a branching process. Chapter $3$ of [this book](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/NotesRGCN.pdf) discusses branching processes. Useful for you would be equation $(3.1.16)$ on page $90$ and Theorem $3.3$ and Theorem $3.5$ on page $92$.

Comment: Thank you for this link. I think it can be (also for me) very useful. It is not customary though to pass this through by means of an answer. A comment would be enough.

Comment: This should indeed be seen as a hint rather than a complete answer. I see that it could also be posted as a comment.